# FQL page_fan_adds for today

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a FQL Query that will retrieve the new fanpage likes for "today". This means it has to update automatically everyday.

Im using the following code:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=481749428508329 AND metric='page_fan_adds' AND end_time=(??????) AND period=86400
```

I've retrieved the object_id by using the Graph API and copy-pasting the id: value. It's for the following page: www.iq-leads.com/IQLeads

I can't seem to figure out how to only get the number of added likes for today. I've tried doing it for a specified date:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=481749428508329 AND metric='page_fan_adds' AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-11-26') AND period=86400
```

and the result is:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure which part of the query is wrong, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The same for me, I can't get it to work. The second example from the [Facebook Insights documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) doesn't work. I guess this is abnormal and it should require Facebook's attention.

Anyway you've got an alternative, it looks like working through the Graph API:
`/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day`

You'll get the result in such a way that the information is gathered by group of three days:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day", 
      "name": "page_fan_adds_unique", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2012-12-17T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2012-12-18T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2012-12-19T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Daily New Likes", 
      "description": "Daily The number of new people who have liked your Page (Unique Users)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day?since=1355425264&until=1355684464", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day?since=1355943664&until=1356202864"
  }
}
```

*(I know, my page isn't really famous)*

Don't forget to use the `read_insights` permission.